# How to set unique template reference variables inside an *ngFor? (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a bunch of input fields in a `*ngFor` loop. The documentation says that template reference variables should be unique. Is there a way to do something like `#attendee-{{person.id}}` to make it unique?

```
   <div *ngFor="let person of attendeesList">
       <input #attendee [ngModel]="person.name" (blur)="changeName(attendee.value)"/>
   </div>
```

(I know that there is the option of doing `(ngModelChange)="changeName($event)"`  but there are reasons I need to use **blur** instead. Specifically, I **don't** want the model to change until the person is done typing the name and we have validated that the name is not empty and not a duplicate name.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your template reference variable is already unique because you use it inside embedded view scope:

```html
<div *ngFor="let person of attendeesList">
  <input #attendee [ngModel]="person.name" (blur)="person.name = attendee.value"/>
</div>
```

**[Working Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/hWXXIFoJRj2losVmjEn1)**

But you can even omit template reference variable as shown below:

```html
<div *ngFor="let person of attendeesList">
  <input [ngModel]="person.name" (blur)="person.name = $event.target.value"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a documentation reference for this? I don't seem to be observing the same behavior.

Comment: @Trevor Can you please demonstrate your issue in stackblitz?

Comment: According to the Angular Guide, passing $event is a dubious practice (https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice). Therefore, your first approach should be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 35):

Template variables need to be unique with respect to the template rather than the rendering of the template (the actual values). You want to use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren).

```
@ViewChildren('attendee') attendeeInputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

You can treat `attendeeInputs` as a [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) and operate on each attendee input individually as needed based on iteration of the indices.

Comment: Straightforward approach - especially if you aren't needing to use ngModel. Thanks for this.

Comment: Could you please tell how to iterate the attendeeeInputs?I'm trying to iterate this but it displays only one array element

Comment: @vishnu try `this.attendeeInputs.map`

Comment: @Explosion Pills Thanks for your reply. Right now I'm using  @ViewChildren('grayBox') grayBox: QueryList<ElementRef>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.grayBox.forEach(loc => {
            console.log(loc.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
        });
    }

Comment: Could you please show  me the same code with map in this?

Comment: @vishnu could you ask your own SO question?

Comment: Yes I have posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66872409/why-iterating-the-viewchildren-querylist-shows-only-one-array-element

Comment: @ExplosionPills how to differ between these `attendeeInputs` if they are `ng-template` (not HTML elements)? There is nothing to hold on to: all `ng-template` (i.e. `TemplateRef`) look the same: no attribute, no class, no unique identifier...

Answer (score 3):

If you have an iterable series of Inputs in your form and a decent amount of logic regarding how you want the form to respond to user input the `ReactiveFormsModule` is going to be a much better fit. This way you don't have to worry about template reference variables and can interact with the FormControls directly.

Essentially with Reactive Forms it would look something like

**Component**

```js
// Initialize your Form
initForm(): void {
    this.Form = this._FormBuilder.group({
        arrayOfInputs: this._FormBuilder.array(initArray())
    })
}

// Initialize the Array of Inputs 
initArray(): FormGroup[] {
    return [
        { this._FormBuilder.group({ inputValue: [''] }),
        { this._FormBuilder.group({ inputValue: [''] }),
        { this._FormBuilder.group({ inputValue: [''] })
    ]
}
```

**Template**

```
<ng-container formArrayName="formArray">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let Inputs of Form.get('arrayOfInputs').controls; let i=index">
        <input formControlName="inputValue" type="text">
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

There's a few things missing here, but generally this is how I build forms that have interable inputs. The major difference is that usually when initializing the FormArray, I am using data pulled from somewhere. It really helps to build your forms in logical chunks.

[Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)