# Cannot read property '0' of undefined angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have the following code posted below. I am trying to make the table editable on click but i am getting the following error provided below. can someone please tell me why that is and what is the workaround for that.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let Accounts of accounts">
      <td >{{Accounts}} </td>
      <td (click)="edit(this)"><input value="{{Accounts}}" disabled onblur="disable(this)"></td>
      <td (click)="edit(this)"><input value="{{Accounts}}" disabled onblur="disable(this)"></td>
      <td (click)="edit(this)"><input value="{{Accounts}}" disabled onblur="disable(this)"></td>
      <td (click)="edit(this)"><input value="{{Accounts}}" disab`enter code here`led onblur="disable(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The typescript code is:

```
public edit(el) {
    el.childNodes[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
    el.childNodes[0].focus();
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }

  public disable(el) {
    el.setAttribute('disabled', '' );
  }
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: i dont think `el` is what you think it is.

Comment: @DanielA.White first off thanks for the response. secondly what do u mean?

Comment: show me accounts array

Comment: childNodes is undefined. Please check the value

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `(click)="edit(this)"`, try `(click)="edit($event)"` (see [Get user input from the $event object](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object)).

In your click handler, you can access the element via `event.target`,

```js
public edit(event) {
  const el = event.target as HTMLElement;
  el.childNodes[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
  el.childNodes[0].focus();
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}

public disable(event) {
  const el = event.target as HTMLElement;
  el.setAttribute('disabled', '' );
}
```

The page [Template reference variables (#var)](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) can also be used (your handler methods remain the same).

You might expect there to be conflict between the rows, but Angular takes care of this problem - see this question [How to set unique template reference variables inside an *ngFor? (Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347854/how-to-set-unique-template-reference-variables-inside-an-ngfor-angular) and the [demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/hWXXIFoJRj2losVmjEn1)

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let Accounts of accounts">
    <td >{{Accounts}} </td>
    <td #cell1 (click)="edit(cell1)"><input value="{{Accounts}}" disabled onblur="disable(cell1)"></td>
    <td #cell2 (click)="edit(cell2)"><input value="{{Accounts}}" disabled onblur="disable(cell2)"></td>
    <td #cell3 (click)="edit(cell3)"><input value="{{Accounts}}" disabled onblur="disable(cell3)"></td>
    <td #cell4 (click)="edit(cell4)"><input value="{{Accounts}}" disabled onblur="disable(cell4)"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: i get the following error `ERROR in src/app/chart-of-accounts/chart-of-accounts.component.ts(62,22): error TS2339: Property 'removeAttribute' does not exist on type 'Node'.
src/app/chart-of-accounts/chart-of-accounts.component.ts(63,22): error TS2339: Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Node'.`