# How to assign Interpolated string into template Ref variables

Tags: angular

Is there a way to assign an element reference variable by interpolating a string into it?

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of studentItems " [class.is-active]="ref.isActive" >
      <a  routerLink="{{item.link}}" routerLinkActive #ref="routerLinkActive">{{item.title}} {{profile}}</a>
      <mat-icon matListIcon class="mat-grey" [class.link-active]="ref.isActive">{{item.icon}}</mat-icon>
</mat-list-item>
```

I am considering variable interpolation for template Ref to gain a unique ref literal for each mat list item otherwise css class would pollute all of the selected and not selected when many items has the same ref .

Comment: Could you give some context; what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Why not define the template reference variable normally (e.g. `#anchor`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  OP edited the Question with a better syntax

Comment: It should work with the same name. Each iteration of the `ngFor` loop will have its own `ref` variable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48347854/1009922).

Comment: @ConnorsFan donno about that but, in this case using  #anchor would set the same class for all the items since they share same ref!

Comment: I am not sure that I get your point. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzssfu).

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes you are right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186524/discussion-between-suhayb-and-connorsfan).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set unique template reference variables inside an \*ngFor? (Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347854/how-to-set-unique-template-reference-variables-inside-an-ngfor-angular)

Answer (score -1):

of course, but with using Angular Router and it's directives

```
<a [routerLink]="item.url"></a>
```

or

```
<a routerLink="https://some_url.com"></a>
```

even anchor links can be provided with Angular Router, using ActivatedRoute fragment property

Comment: That's not the case actually, please check the edits

Comment: you can place the routerLinkActive directive on mat-list-item, you can pass to it the class you need (not only "active") eg routerLinkActive="any-class"