# angular setting unique reference #name to component

Tags: angular

Yes. This is a duplicate.

I ask exactly the same with this:

[How to set unique template reference variables inside an *ngFor? (Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347854/how-to-set-unique-template-reference-variables-inside-an-ngfor-angular)

However, in the issue above, the exact question was not answered but offered alternatives.

So, I ask only for this: **Is it even possible to give unique names using "#"** (I could not find how to call this method, giving name by #. Does someone know, please?)

I ask this because, for example, `mat-menu` works with #names.

Please see the examples here:

[Angular Mat-Menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview)

As you see, [matMenuTriggerFor] refers to #names.

But what about creating the menus dynamically? Then how would I refer to it with [matMenuTriggerFor]?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclamer** I don't see the links of the question, it's the same answer, sorry

In general you has no problem indicate the same template reference in a *ngFor, "fool example"

```
<div *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">
   <input #input [value]="i"/>
   <button (click)="input.value=2*input.value">double</button>
</div>
```

There're no confused about what "input" double his value, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hctu3v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

If you want to control outside the loop the inputs, you can use ViewChildren. In our .ts

```
  @ViewChildren('input') inputs:QueryList<ElementRef>
  click()
  {
    this.inputs.forEach(x=>{
        x.nativeElement.value=2*x.nativeElement.value
    })
  }
```

And a button

```
<button (click)="click()">Double All</button>
```

NOTE: You can use directly "inputs" in the .html

```
<button (click)="this.inputs.first.nativeElement.value=
          2*this.inputs.first.nativeElement.value">
    Double first input
</button>
```

Comment: How would you access to specific element of #input in the html?

Comment: using ViewChildren in "inputs" has all the `<input #input >`. Its a QueryList, so you can use the methods of QueryList, https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList. If you want to access to the n-th element, you need convert To Array: `this.inputs.toArray()[n]`, or, if has attributes you can find using some like `this.inputs.find(x=>x.nativeElement.getAttributes('type')=='date')`, e.g. But **really** I don't know what are you trying to do. If you make some "dinamic" you use generally some like `<div *ngFor="let item of elements">`, If are buttons,e.g.you can use some like `(click)="myfunction(item)`