# Dynamics hashtag with angular 7 in ngFor and get value

Tags: angular, angular7, angular2-template, ngfor

I need a help.
So my code in angular 7 is:
(html)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let camera of cameraArray; let i = index">      
    <div class="border-padding">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Temperatura camera (°C)" #valuecamera1TempCamera value="{{camera1.STP_TempCamera}}">
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="sendCommand(1100, valuecamera1TempCamera.value, camera1)">Invia temperatura camera</button>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

So, my question is, is it possible to make this dynamic: `#valuecamera1TempCamera`
for example my target will be: `#valuecamera{{i}}TempCamera`

and after I call the method `sendCommand(1100, valuecamera{{i}}TempCamera.value, camera1)`

Is it possible to make #myvar dynamics in angular ? Or, is there any other solutions ?
Thanks

Comment: I've had the same issue some time ago and after a few hours of pain I ended up just reiterating over a reusable component and then building that logic inside that reusable component and just passing all the data as an Input property.

Comment: Please don't ask XY problems. You should first explain what you're trying to do, and then what you've tried. You're clearly trying to handle multiple inputs across multiple camera objects. Dynamically changing template references is not the best solution. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Really you needn't change the template reference, use an unique into the loop, Angular understand that, inside the loop, -in the (click)- the input is the correct, try it ;), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316637/angular-setting-unique-reference-name-to-component/58316865#58316865

Answer (score 4):

Turns out you don't need dynamic references. The `ngFor` directive handles this. Checkout the stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-template-ref)

You could also use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) to get the references in your component. You get an array-like list of all of the elements that match that property. There's also a changes property thats an observable, so you're able to listen to any changes.

Comment: same comment to the other answer

Comment: @Eliseo thanks! I learnt something today. Updated my answer with stackblitz demo

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a thing as dynamic template references in Angular unfortunately.
Check those links for possible workarounds:

[Dynamic template reference variable inside ngFor (Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2)

[Access multiple viewchildren using @viewchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild/40165639#40165639)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316637/angular-setting-unique-reference-name-to-component/58316865#58316865