# #identifier="someModule" syntax explanation

Tags: angular

You often see the following syntax in templates:

```
<form #df="ngForm">
...
<button (click)="submitForm(df)">
```

Today I managed to use this syntax with `ngbTooltip`, in order to popup a tooltip programmatically:

```
<button #tooltipRef="ngbTooltip" ngbTooltip="Some info!" (click)="bringUpTooltip(tooltipRef)
[ngClass]="{'font-weight-bold' : someProperty.shouldBeBold, 'text-nowrap row' : true}">>
```

However, I do not understand the mechanism completely, because when I use it in order to get a reference for something else (for example, `#classRef="ngClass"` or `#boldRef="someProperty.shouldBeBold"`) I would get an error:

`Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
 There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "someProperty.shouldBeBold"`

It's very often that I find it difficult to dynamically pass references from template to component. When the reference is singular across the template, I can use `ViewChild` but when it is within a `ngFor` loop then I have no immediate solution.

I guess my question is how to fully leverage the `#identity="module"`syntax.

Thank you

Comment: I think this would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347854/how-to-set-unique-template-reference-variables-inside-an-ngfor-angular

Answer (score 1):

When you use `@ViewChild` with a reference variable, you get an ElementRef.

```
@ViewChild('ref',{static:false}) element:ElementRef
```

But you can indicate that it's not only a ElementRef, else is a type of a Component (or perhafs you're interesting in a ViewContainerRef)

```
@ViewChild('ref',{static:false,read:MyComponent}) element:MyComponent
```

How indicate in .html? Exactly, using the way

```
  <tag #tagRef="MyComponent"></tag>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how this explains my example with.`ngbTooltip`? I was able to reference an unrelated component and attach it to a `button`

Comment: Well, I think that ngbTooltip is a "attribute directive", in some way "transform" the button in a "super-button", You're interesting in the "supper button" methods (sorry, I'm just an amateur of Angular and it's possible this examplain is not fully correct)