# Material Chip Input with ngFor - template reference loop

Tags: angular

I'm trying to loop and create Material chip inputs dynamically, e.g:

```
<section *ngFor="let basket of baskets">

<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of basket.fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(basket, fruit)">
      {{fruit.name}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="New fruit..."
           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add(basket, $event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>

</section>
```

It's not really going to work since there is a template reference (`#chipList`) which is used here: `[matChipInputFor]="chipList"` and I want each chip input to remove/add its own items. Since template reference is unique, it won't work inside an `*ngFor`.

I've tried to use `@ViewChildren`:

```
@ViewChildren(MatChipList) chipLists: QueryList<MatChipList>;
```

but I'm unable to filter by class, and when I do use `{ read: ElementRef }` - I need to save the MatChipList reference and not the element ref.

Any idea of what is the ideal way to loop and create those mat chip inputs dynamically for each `basket`?

Comment: Can you share your component's code? It is not clear what you failed to achieve.

Comment: @Eldar The code above is not working, the template reference to the chip list (`#chipList`) is unique - inside a loop it doesn't really works.

Comment: The question is why you need that reference in the first place?

Comment: @Eldar I have to send it to the input, `[matChipInputFor]="chipList"`

Comment: Sorry I missed that part of code. Made this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chipinput-dqj71f) check if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can use it like that based on the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347854/how-to-set-unique-template-reference-variables-inside-an-ngfor-angular). The values can be handled using the form controls.
In my case, I had autocomplete with the chips which I then used `viewChildren` to handle closing

Answer (score -1):

First the input element must be outside the mat-chip-list I think this is the issue in your code because angular create separated references by default with building directives like *ngFor.

```
<section *ngFor="let basket of baskets">

<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of basket.fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(basket, fruit)">
      {{fruit.name}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>

  <input placeholder="New fruit..."
           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add(basket, $event)">
</mat-form-field>

</section>
```

Please refer to this demo on click the console reference each template-ref separately even they declared with same name: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b6jyqp)

The console will show the difference as follows:
[image]