# Why iterating the ViewChildren QueryList shows only one array element?

Tags: angular

I want to  know the height of each div element with the reference myRef and store them in an array. In the console it shows only one value. Whereas I save the reference variables using ViewChildren  in QueryList. Please help me to find the issue. Thank.

the html file

```
<div *ngFor="let person of attendeesList">
<div #myRef>
{{person.familyDetails}}
</div>
</div>
```

the ts file

```
@ViewChildren('#myRef') myRef : QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit()
{
this.myRef.forEach((attendees)=>{
console.log(attendees.nativeElement.offsetHeight);
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild` and you need to remove the `#` from `#myRef`:

`@ViewChildren('myRef') myRef : QueryList<ElementRef>;`

I managed to fix the problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7aqde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yes I'm using ViewChildren, sorry but mistake I mentioned ViewChild in my question. I changes it. Even after using @ViewChildren it is not working

Comment: you need to change `#myRef` to `myRef`

Comment: I used the same thing but it doesn't work. Actually all these ts code and html are part of my child component. Could that be an issue?

Comment: can you post both parent and child code (ts + html) ?

Comment: Okay, I'll post it

Comment: Actually i don't have much code in the parent and child componets. In the parent I have the code to pass data to child component.

Comment: I want to know how to increase my parent component's height dynamically when the child component 's height increases.